# Testing string equality using hashCode()

Tags: java, string, hashcode

Is there any reason why a Java string cannot be tested for equality using its hashCode method?  So basically, instead of....

```
"hello". Equals("hello")
```

You could use...

```
"hello".hashCode() == "hello".hashCode()
```

This would be useful because once a string has calculated it's hashcode then comparing a string would be as efficient as comparing an int as the string caches the hashcode and it is quite likely that the string is in the string pool anyway, if you designed it that way.

Comment: Your answer lies in the documentation on the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

Comment: And regarding efficiency: take a close look at the strings that you're comparing. I'll be willing to bet that > 50% differ in their first character, and > 66% differ in their first two characters. So you actually have a very efficient comparison versus hashCode(), which has to walk the entire string. Plus, if you're using strings in the constant pool, equals() first checks identity, which will kick those out right away.

Comment: @kdgregory It's true that the worst case scenario is that the strings actually match, which might also be the most common scenario.  You've also answered my underlying string performance question, any gains being made by a pooled hashcode is being made already be performing an instance check.  Cheers!

Comment: What I find strange is that the current String implementation caches the hashCode, but does not use it in equals(), even though it would be a quick way to eliminate unequal strings in many cases - a big gain in the (admittedly rare) case where you compare strings with long identical prefixes.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

because: hashCodes of two objects must be equal  if the objects are equal, however, if two objects are unequal, the hashCode can still be equal.

(modified after comment)

Comment: +1, hashcodes don't guarantee uniqueness - they only try and provide low collisions

Comment: +1, however one small ammendment. hashCodes of two objects MUST be equal if the objects are equal, this is specified in the contract of hashCode.

Comment: Short and correct answer. Also doing something like that just to be as efficient as possible sounds a bit like premature optimization to me.

Comment: This would be a problem if you were testing against user input for example.  If you were testing strings in a controlled environment and could guarantee no collisions (unit tests) then it would be worth it if it gave marked performance improvements but as kdgregory pointed out above it would not.

Cheers!

Comment: @andy Theoretically, I guess. But you'd have to verify that your strings did not give hash collisions. And then if later someone changes the program and adds a new string, they'd have to know to check if that creates a hash collision, and if so, they would then have to change all the comparisons. You'd be far better off to create an Enum or otherwise assign your own unique identifier to each string, rather than relying on the hashcodes not having collisions basically out of luck.

Answer (score 40):

Let me give you a counter example. Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "0-42L";
    String str2 = "0-43-";

    System.out.println("String equality: " + str1.equals(str2));
    System.out.println("HashCode eqauality: " + (str1.hashCode() == str2.hashCode()));
}
```

The result on my Java,

```
String equality: false
HashCode eqauality: true
```

Comment: Is it a coincidence that these two strings with the hash code collision are so similar? (i.e., the first three characters are the same.) Or are two similar strings also more likely to have a hash code collision?

Answer (score 16):

as many said hashCode does not guaranty uniqueness.
in fact, it cannot do that for a very simple reason.

hashCode returns an int, which means there are 2^32 possible values (around 4,000,000,000), but there are surely more than 2^32 possible strings, which means at least two strings have the same hashcode value.

this is called [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: good answer, could have done with knowing about pigeonhole principle in a recent interview

Comment: Way more than two, if you think about it. If the max length of a string is Integer.MAX_VALUE, i.e. about 2 billion, and there are 2^32 ~= 64k possible char values, then there are (2^32)^(2^31) possible strings vs 2^32 hash values, means there are (2^32)^(2^31) / (2^32) = (2^32)^(2^30) strings for any given hash code. Which comes out to about 10 ^ 9 billion. i.e. a Very Big Number.

Comment: @Jay: "2^32 ~= 64k"? What does ~= mean here?

Comment: "Approximately equal to". The conventional math symbol for that isnot readily entered on most keyboards.

Comment: Two is all you need to demonstrate that it cannot guaranty uniqueness.
obviously the number of possible hash collisions for strings is too long to fit into this comment.

Comment: @OmryYadan Quite true. I just found it amusing to beat the subject to death.

Answer (score 8):

Others have pointed out why it won't work. So I'll just add the addendum that the gain would be minimal anyway.

When you compare two strings in Java, the String equals function first checks if they are two references to the same object. If so, it immediately returns true. Then it checks if the lengths are equal. If not, it returns false. Only then does it start comparing character-by-character.

If you're manipulating data in memory, the same-object compare may quickly handle the "same" case, and that's a quick, umm, 4-byte integer compare I think. (Someone correct me if I have the length of an object handle wrong.)

For most unequal strings, I'd bet the length compare quickly finds them not equal. If you're comparing two names of things -- customers, cities, products, whatever -- they'll usually have unequal length. So a simple int compare quickly disposes of them.

The worst case for performance is going to be two long, identical, but not the same object strings. Then it has to do the object handle compare, false, keep checking. The length compare, true, keep checking. Then character by character through the entire length of the string to verify that yes indeed they are equal all the way to the end.

Comment: Good answer. This would have benefitted from mention of the intern method which makes the strict equality check more likely to matter.

Comment: @Spina Valid point. If both strings are String literals, then yes, their objects will compare equal. If they are read from a database or user input, then you could intern them so their objects would compare equal. Whether this is of value depends how often you compare the strings.

Comment: There are some cases where one would be likely to perform many comparisons against long strings that may be almost identical, and in such cases, pre-checking hash codes may be useful.  In such cases, however, the code using the strings is free to check the hash code before testing equality.

Comment: @supercat For this to help, you would have to calculate the hash codes once and cache them, and you would have to be doing comparisons against the same string multiple times. It's more work to calculate the hash codes for two string than to compare two strings: you have to examine every character in a string to compute the hash code, and do some arithmetic on top of that. So if you only compare a given string once, you'd be doing more work to calculate the hash than it would take to just do the compare, and then if the hash comes out equal, you still have to do the compare, so it's ...

Comment: ... lose/lose. If you do compare the same string multiple times, and you are comparing it against other strings of equal length that are the same for the first some-number of characters, then calculating the hash could help. Frankly, that's the sort of optimization that is highly dependent on implementation details and the combination of data that you happen to have. You'd really have to study the details to see if it would help or hurt. BTW the current implementation of java.lang.String does cache hash-codes the first time they are requested, so you wouldn't need to cache them yourself.

Comment: @Jay: My point was that sometimes the code which is using strings will have specialized knowledge about the content of other strings against which they're going to be compared, and code *with such knowledge* may sometimes find pre-comparisons of hash codes useful.  It is entirely reasonable for code with such knowledge to compare string hash codes as a prelude to comparing their values.  Such hash-based comparisons belong in the code which *uses* the strings, though, rather than in the `String` class itself.

Comment: @Jay: Incidentally, unless near matches are going to be more common than matches, caching hash codes isn't apt to be as useful as wrapping the strings in a class which builds equivalence sets.  If each instance holds an "age" value [a `long` that gets incremented each time one is created], a `string`, and a reference to an older instance which is known to match, then when two wrapper objects find that distinct string instances match, whichever one holds a reference to a "newer" string can be updated to hold the oldest string instance that's known to be equal.

Comment: @supercat Sure. Given sufficient knowledge of your data, I'm sure they're are all sorts of optimizations once could do. Like if the strings are some sort of code and you know that the only possible string values are "aasdopfu", "aasdopfv", and "aasdoxfu", you might well be better off to just example each one as it arrives and translate it to a standard integer value, like 1, 2, and 3 respectively. If you know your strings all tend to begin the same but end differently, you might want to write your own compare that checks from the end backwards. Etc. It all depends on the nature of the ...

Comment: ... data, and on how big an issue performance is and how much work you're willing to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the effect you want using `String.intern()` (which is implemented using a hash table.)

You can compare the return values of `intern()` using the `==` operator.  If they refer to the same string then the original strings were equivalent (i.e. `equals()` would have returned `true`), and it requires only a pointer comparison (which has the same cost as an `int` comparison.)

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "Hel" + "lo";

System.out.println(a.equals(b));
System.out.println(a == b);

String a2 = a.intern();
String b2 = b.intern();

System.out.println(a2.equals(b2));
System.out.println(a2 == b2);
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

The hashCode value isn't unique, which means the Strings may not actually match.  To improve performance, often implementations of equals will perform a hashCode check before performing more laborious checks.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple reason: risk of collisions...
A hash code will have a lot less possible values than a string. It depends a bit of the kind of hash you generate but let's take a very simple example, where you would add the ordinal values of letters, multiplied with it's position: a=1, b=2, etc. Thus, 'hello' would translate to:
h: 8x1=8, e: 5x2=10, l: 12x3=36, l: 12x4=48, o: 15x5=75. 8+10+36+48+75=177.

Are there other string values that could end as 177 hashed? Of course! Plenty of options. Feel free to calculate a few.

Still, this hashing method used a simple method. Java and .NET use a more complex hashing algorithm with a lot smaller chance of such collisions. But still, there's a chance that two different strings will result in the same hash value, thus this method is less reliable.

Comment: zzzda would also equal 177. (1x26, 2x26, 3x26, 4x4, 5x1)

Answer (score 0):

Two different String can easily generate same hash Code or different hash Code.
If u want a equality test hash Code won't give an unique result. When we use String class it will return different value of hash Code. So String buffer class should be apply to have same hash Code for every concated  object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason why a Java string cannot be tested for equality
> using its hashCode method?

Equality check is never done with `hashCode()` method be it String or any other object in Java.

The purpose of `hashCode()` is totally different and certainly not related to equality checks.

Here is the excerpt from the [java.lang.Object's equals() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

The real essence of overridden `hashCode()` can be experienced when you are dealing with Hash based collections like HashSet, HashMap or HashTable in Java.

For strings always use `equals()` method to check if two strings are equal. Why? Because `java.lang.String` has overridden `java.lang.Object`'s equals() to compare strings by value instead of referential equality using `==` operator.

**Note:** Referential equality check using `==` is not same as hashCode() comparison.

Answer (score -2):

There is no reason not to use hashCode as you describe.

However, you must be aware of collisions.  There is a chance - a small chance admittedly - that two different strings do hash to the same value.  Consider doing a hashCode at first, and if equal also do the full comparison using the equals().

Comment: So in other words, there is a reason to not use hashcode as he describes?

Comment: so there's no reason to dismiss it out of hand, only a warning to do additional checks in some circumstances

Comment: So if you still have to do the equals test, why bother? You've just written twice as much code to get to the same place.

Comment: if the assumption is that the strings are unlikely to be similiar, you'd get the efficiency that the asker queried.

Comment: I should say that back when I was writing demo apps for early j2me phones, for the manufacturers, and performance even of this kind of thing really mattered, using hashCode() to cheapen comparisons is the kind of thing we did all the time.  You need profiling to back it up, but its worth exploring in the most performance-critical code.