# Is using hashCode to implement equals a no go?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have been experimenting with the following implementation of equals & hashCode:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj != null && hashCode() == obj.hashCode();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(myField1).append(myField2).toHashCode();
}
```

Basically, I am expecting `equals` to return `true` for any 2 classes having the same `hashCode`, which comes down to the values of the fields I am using to generate my hashCode.

I am aware that this also returns `true` for *different classes* that happen to have equal values in these fields.

**Question: What are pitfalls of such an implementation?**

Comment: @Jonas Eicher, you may want to have a look at [Testing string equality using hashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465621/testing-string-equality-using-hashcode "Testing string equality using hashCode()").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hash collisions.  Instances with different field values may have matching hashcodes, and therefore compare equal.  I'm not sure why this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

As Oli said, you will ensure that 2 objects with the same data match, but also a non matching objects with the same hashCode will do, remember you use hashcode to order elements in hash tables to optimize the sorting not for comparing, for ensure the equals methods you should compare your delicate data for the object like:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof THISOBJECT) {
        THISOBJECT other = (THISOBJECT) obj;
        return getID.equals(other.getID);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If testing two objects for equality would be expensive, and if the hash codes of the objects are known, it may be helpful to test the hash codes as a *first step* toward testing equality.  If the hash codes are not equal, there's no need to look any further.  If they are equal, then examine things in more detail.  Suppose, for example, that one had many 100,000-character strings which happened to differed only in the last ten characters (but there was no reason to expect that to be the case).  Even if there were a 1% false match rate with hash codes, checking hash codes before checking the string contents in detail could offer a nearly-100-fold speedup versus repeatedly having to examining the first 9,990 characters of every strings.

The goal of a hash code is generally not to be unique, but rather to reduce the cost of comparisons involving false hash matches to be in the same ballpark as the cost of hash code computations.  If a given hash code generates so many false matches that the time spent processing those dominates the time computing the hash codes, then spending more time computing hash codes may be worthwhile if it can reduce the number of false matches.  If the hash algorithm is so effective that the time spent computing hash codes dominates the time spent on false matches, it may be better to use a faster hashing algorithm even if the number of false matches would increase.

Comment: Hmm, comparing hash codes (generally) requires processing all N characters; I'm not sure the statistics of your example is correct...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If code is asked to compare two instances it's never seen before and does not expect to see again, computing the hashcodes would not be worthwhile.  On the other hand, if it's given an instance and will have to compare it--and many other instances--against instances which it receives in future (think `HashSet`) it can cache its hash code computation.  Further, with some types like `String`, "computing" a hash code 1,000 times will usually only require iterating over the string once and then caching the computation result [too bad that Sun didn't add a line to their...

Comment: ...`String` hash method to the effect of `if (computation == 0) return 0x12345678; else return computation;`, since that simple change would have made string hash caching "always" work].

Comment: is hashCode not called at every hash comparison and so calculated every time anyway? Or do you mean to cache the hashCode of an object and then refresh it on property changes?

Comment: @JonasEicher: Most objects that override `hashCode()` are observationally immutable, so property changes are not a factor.  Otherwise, I would suggest that if hashcode computations have any significant cost, property changes should invalidate cached hash codes rather than recalculating them.